# truncate "hh:mm:ss" to have just "hh"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Looking to trim/truncate time into just hours in Excel.

For example, if right now is "09:08:32"

I would like to isolate "09" and have it in another cell so that I can use it for an equation.

Comment: This depends on your actual data. Is the data on the cell is stored as a text, or this is an actual date/time formatted cell? If it is Text = just use =LEFT(cell,2) to pick up the 2-left-most characters (09). If it is an actual date/time format, you can change the date/time format to just show hh (after you copy the data into the new cell or simply use =OriginalCell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your time is stored properly as time, you can use this formula:

`=HOUR(A1)`

If it's stored as text, then use this:

`=VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))`

Both cases, if you want to display `09` instead of `9`, then right-click on your cell, select number formatting - custom and enter `00`.

Answer (score 2):

Create the custom cell format directly, select the cell and right click- select **Format Cells...**- Under **Number** tab select **Custom** and enter `hh`

[image]